# Is there a YAML test suite?

Tags: yaml, test-suite

A comprehensive test suite would be a valuable tool to have, especially when evaluating all of the variant parsers out there.  Does such a beast exist?

In a perfect world, I imagine it would have different sections for different versions of the YAML spec...

Comment: This started as a question about a particular case for a particular set of parsers, but I thought I'd broaden things...

Comment: The PyYAML source has a quite extensive test system for testing each stage of the the parsing and generation against many parts of the (1.1) specification.

Comment: I thought I'd get JSON+comments for free by specifying YAML as an interop language, but if something as basic as JSON+comments is tripping up common libraries, than forget it.  e.g. php's Symfony YAML parser chokes on  http://pastebin.com/R8GzNpwC but other parser/validators say it's fine.  It's probably fine, but why should I have to wonder?

Comment: That is legal YAML, you can have comments even in flow style. My parser (ruamel.yaml) parses it without problem, although the comments are lost on round-tripping (which wouldn''t happen when it is a block mapping). File a bug. Use a better parser if available for PHP,  switch languages if you can. Or preprocess in an external process is my recommendation (ping me if you put up a question on how to do that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently one in the making, see [here](https://github.com/yaml/yaml-test-suite).

We also generate a [result matrix](http://matrix.yaml.io/) for YAML implementations which

- we know of
- are written in a language we know so we can implement adapter code to validate the test suite against it

Full disclosure: I am the author of [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org) and some of the test cases and adapters.